# Why is this query giving me incorrect division?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a query that brings back the following tables. The last column I've created divides `Total_points` by `Games_played` in order to get the `Points_Per_Game` figure in the last column.

This is the table

```
+----------+--------------+--------+-----------------+
| PlayerID | Games_Played | Points | Points_Per_Game |
+----------+--------------+--------+-----------------+
|       16 |            2 |      3 |          0.6000 |
|       20 |            2 |      3 |          0.6000 |
|       10 |            2 |      3 |          0.3750 |
|       18 |            2 |      3 |          0.3750 |
|        5 |            2 |      3 |          0.3750 |
|        9 |            2 |      3 |          0.3750 |
+----------+--------------+--------+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the query

```
SELECT Players.PlayerID, COUNT(Games.Points) AS Games_Played, 
SUM(Games.Points) AS Points, SUM(Points/Games_Played) AS Points_Per_Game
FROM Teams, Players, Games

WHERE 
Teams.PlayerID=Players.PlayerID
AND
Games.Game=Teams.Game
AND
Games.Team=Teams.Team
AND
Games.GameDate=Teams.GameDate
AND
(
CONCAT(Games.Game, '_', Games.GameDate)= 
ANY(SELECT CONCAT(Teams.Game, '_', Teams.GameDate) 
FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='4')
AND NOT
CONCAT(Games.Game, '_', Games.Team, '_', Games.GameDate)= 
ANY(SELECT CONCAT(Teams.Game, '_', Teams.Team, '_', Teams.GameDate) 
FROM Teams WHERE PlayerID='4')

)

GROUP BY Teams.PlayerID
ORDER By Points_per_Game DESC, Points DESC, Games_Played;
```

Is is something to do with the fact that I am grouping by and summing the columns that are referenced?

I can't seem to see why this isn't coming out as 1.5

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Games played doesn't llook right

Comment: @Strawberry I'll take the suggestion on board definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try....

```
SELECT Players.PlayerID, COUNT(Games.Game) AS Games_Played, 
SUM(Games.Points) AS Points, SUM(Games.Points)/COUNT(Games.Game) AS Points_Per_Game
FROM Teams, Players, Games
```

Your Games_Played wasn't correct or at best misleading.

Also, I'd recommend that you look into using JOINS to connect Teams, Games & Players.

Comment: Thanks for this @AntDC from your previous comment Games_Played is correct at two games. I had tried `SUM(SUM(Games.Points)/COUNT(Games.Game))` but didn't think to try the way you had suggested, but it works perfectly.